# API to add an option gives me an error: {"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"option"}}

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I've been using the Magento API for a while now, and create products via it, as I am now using 'Option' in a dropdown I want to populate it if the option is not found....

As such, I am using the following JSON:

```
{
  "option": {
    "label": "14",
    "value": "14",
    "sort_order": 0,
    "is_default": true,
  }
}
```

Looking at the swagger document, this should be accepted! I'm posting to the following URL:

/index.php/rest/V1/products/attributes//options

I get the following error:

```
{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"option"}}
```

But, I'm specifying option in the JSON.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello toby have youళ  checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

> Your **url** is in-correct

```
http://magento.host/rest/V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}/options
```

- `method GET`

---

1. you are missing **{attributeCode}** in your URL.

   - `Parameters` - `attributeCode` is **required**.
2. It will Retrieve list of attribute options.

Comment: It striped out my attribute code in between the two slashes! I am putting the attribute in there...

Comment: great !! it will work follow the steps :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t clear. My post in here stripped out the attribute code, you can see I have a double // in my original post URL. I put the attribute code between that. So the URL seems correct and the swagger doc seems to say this should be valid.

Comment: Please share your screen.